# Lock implementation based on JDBC

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, locking

The problem: I'm preparing single-instance application to become multi-instance. There are a lot of `Lock` usages (from `java.util.concurrent.locks` package) to synchronize access to some resources (external files on other server). Now for synchronizing `ReentrantLock` implementation of `Lock` is used.

To share locks between instances I want to use PostgreSQL database table which is already connected via JDBC. Since all consumers uses only `Lock` interface (not uses `ReentrantLock` class directly) I want to replace `Lock` implementation with `Lock` based on database table.

What is the correct way to implement `Lock` based on database table? Or maybe any standard `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` implementation based on JDBC exists?

UPDATE:
I'm not looking for table locking mechanism (like in [Table lock in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570005/table-lock-in-postgresql) question), I need `Lock` implementation to use it in-code, not in SQL.

Comment: If there is some specific reason for using the synchronization using the jdbc or you want to use synchronization in multi instance scenarios

Comment: @Dinesh no, I can use any multi-instance synchronization, but JDBC based would be more desirable, because it's the only fast and shared resource for all instance, which is already connected.